# Jquery push array of array values

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have appending my input boxes when click button.I need to push all the text box values into array of array.(i.e)`[['',2,3],['',3,4]]`.It pushes only the first input box values.You can find below my working code snippet. Any one help me to figure it out what i done wrongly.

```js
var data = [['',2,3]];

$('button').on('click',function(){
 $("#clone").append('<input id="name"/><input id="type">');
    var name = $('.name').val();
    var type = $('.type').val();
    //var id = parseInt(data.items[data.items.length-1].id)+1;
        
    data.push(["",name,type]);
    console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clone">
  <input id="name" class="name"/>
  <input id="type" class="type"/>
</div>
<button>click</button>
```

Comment: Please explain your question more and please share the required output format as well correctly.

Comment: When I click button ,need to append the input boxes at the same time have to push the entered the values into array of array format([['',1,2],['',5,6]]). for example i have initial array [[]].when entering values need to push into that array and the text boxes need to clone. final o/p:[['',1,2],['',5,6],['',7,8]] like wise how many input boxes are cloned and add push values into the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery selectors are wrong.
You should change `.name` and `.type` to `#name` and `#type` resp.

Here is the link for [Official jQuery Documentation for Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/#post-271)

```js
var data = [['',2,3]];

$('button').on('click',function(){
var name = $('.name').last().val()
    var type = $('.type').last().val()
 $(".clone").append('<input class="name" /><input class="type">');
    
    //var id = parseInt(data.items[data.items.length-1].id)+1;
        
    data.push(["",name,type]);
    console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clone">
  <input class="name"/>
  <input  class="type"/>
</div>
<button>click</button>
```

Comment: @bravemaster hello your answer not giving correct resutl

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. That's because the original code clones div using same id. That's a bad practice I know. But I wanted to stick to the original. But it seems like I have to change some structure. :)

Comment: but i need to append the same text boxed.That's what i am confusing how to get the the result